# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to contact after a delay

Tags: keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu on a machine acting as mostly server. I have 2 problems.

1. When I power up the machine, keyboard and mouse works it is also possible to use Remote desktop. But if I leave it for some time (next day) no matter how hard I hit the keyboard or mouse nothing happens. If I try using Remote desktop I can connect but all I get is a black window. The machine is running i can connect to the Samba shares and the virtual http-servers are responding.
2. When computer isn't interacted with in some minutes the screen goes black as it should, but not completely. It is more like dark gray and so the screen never detects it and turn off completely.

```
 *-display 
     description: VGA compatible controller 
     product: ASPEED Graphics 
     Family vendor: ASPEED Technology, Inc. 
     physical id: 0 
     bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
     logical name: /dev/fb0 
     version: 30 
     width: 32 bits 
     clock: 33MHz 
     capabilities: pm msi vga_controller cap_list rom fb 
     configuration: depth=32 driver=ast latency=0 resolution=1920,1080 
     resources: irq:16 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:df000000-df01ffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: There is no info here to given any clues as to what you are experiencing. Are talking about what appears to be a video issue with no mention of graphics card or drivers. Also the kernel info would help.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Kernel version 5.15.0-69-generic
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: ASPEED Graphics Family
       vendor: ASPEED Technology, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 30
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=ast latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:16 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:df000000-df01ffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: The main problem is having to restart the server if it have been running for "to long". The screen not going black is annoying but still a minor issue.